# Using ActiveRecord to find a many to many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm still pretty inexperienced with Rails' activerecord and I'm struggling to find a good way to match up multiple records that are associated with multiple other records.

I'm running a league with multiple seasons and teams.  I want to find all teams that are in the currently active seasons.  So...multiple seasons and multiple teams.

The models:

```
class Season < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :team_seasons, :dependent => :delete_all
    has_many :teams, :through => :team_seasons
end

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :team_seasons, :dependent => :delete_all
  has_many :seasons, :through => :team_seasons
end
```

I am thinking it should be something like `@teams = Team.includes(:seasons).where(:active => true)` but the sql this returns is `SELECT`teams`.* FROM`teams`WHERE`teams`.`active`= 1` which is just checking whether the team is active and not checking the seasons at all.  Plus that query takes a LONG time to run.

So...is there a good way to do this?  I know I could just make a manual sql statement but I really would like to be able to use and learn the activerecord way to do this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `@teams = Team.includes(:seasons).where("seasons.active = true")` did the trick.